# How to get post_id by multi meta_value with sql query

Tags: wordpress

if have a post,

```
id = 10

meta_key = size
meta_value = xxl

meta_key = color
meta_value = red
```

how can i get this `post_id` with **sql** like this

```
$my_post_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( " SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'xxl' "),'ARRAY_A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base query for that would be

```sql
SELECT post_id 
  FROM wp_postmeta 
 WHERE meta_key   IN ('size', 'color')
   AND meta_value IN ('xxl', 'red')
 GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key)   = 2 
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT meta_value) = 2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91895/1)** demo